# Data to string in UTF-8 encoding format conversion return nil in PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate's generateRequestWithCertificateChain method

Tags: swift, wallet, passkit

I am implementing Apple Wallet, where I need to add the card to the wallet. I am trying to convert the certificates, nonce and nonceSignature that I am receiving in the addPaymentPassViewController(_:generateRequestWithCertificateChain:nonce:nonceSignature:completionHandler:) delegate method of PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate of PassKit, from 'Data' to String encoded in 'UTF8' format.

However, the conversion returns nil while converting from Data to String using utf8 encoding format.

Pls find an image attached. I have highlighted where the conversion fails

Could any please help me to identify what is going wrong?

```
class ViewController: PKAddPaymentPassViewControllerDelegate {
    func addPaymentPassViewController(_ controller: PKAddPaymentPassViewController, generateRequestWithCertificateChain certificates: [Data], nonce: Data, nonceSignature: Data, completionHandler handler: @escaping (PKAddPaymentPassRequest) -> Void) {
        
        var encodedCertificateString = ""
        for index in 0..<certificates.count {
            if let encodedCertString = String(data: certificates[index], encoding: .utf8) {
                encodedCertificateString.append(encodedCertString)
                if index != (certificates.count-1) {
                    encodedCertificateString.append(", ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addPaymentPassViewController(_ controller: PKAddPaymentPassViewController, didFinishAdding pass: PKPaymentPass?, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't not utf8 encoded String (DER encoded X.509 certificate), so that your call was failed. You have to download root CA to validate the chain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please elaborate on root CA

Comment: Apple root CA can be obtained from the certificate authority. Below is the link to get the Apple root CA,
https://www.apple.com/appleca/AppleIncRootCertificate.cer